# Hibernate session management

Tags: hibernate, session, sessionfactory

I'm using hibernate and have some trouble in how to use session, which is best method :

1. use one session and open it in singleton

   ```
   public static CommonServiceImpl getInstance() {

       if (session == null ||  !session.isOpen() ) {
           session = sessionFactory.openSession();
       }
       //session.clear();
       return instance;
   }
   ```
2. Use `SessionFactory` each time when i wanna use the session with `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The session object is designed to be a lightweight, disposable object
that you can open and dispose on demand..
You should not try to reuse it on your own (like singleton)
The real problem is thread safety:
while the SessionFactory object is thread safe, the session object is not
and will cause havoc when pointed from several threads.
If you don't want to open a new session every time you can use the current session option which allows you to bind a session to a specific context (like a thread) within the session factory and then [retrieve](http://www.dil.univ-mrs.fr/~massat/docs/hibernate-3.1/api/org/hibernate/SessionFactory.html#getCurrentSession%28%29) it each time..

Comment: thanks Pavel, really that helped me  :)
i found that the best solution is switching to Spring session management